# Object initialized in the main class and using the same object in a method/function for different purpose?

Tags: java

I have a class that contains the following coding

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class someClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product[] p= new Product[3];
        p[0] = new Product();
        p[1] = new Product();
        p[2] = new Product();
        p[0].name="John";    // Product is a class which contains variable String name;  
                             // and a method getName() which is returning the name;
        p[1].name="Tony";
        p[2].name="Abraham";
        somePrintMethod();
    }

    public static void somePrintMethod() {
        for(int i =0;i<3;i++) {
            System.out.println(p[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is can I use the object defined in the main class in any other method for other

purpose in the same class or there is any method to use that object because I am trying to

do that and it is giving me an error and I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: Please format your code properly (select it all in the editor, and click the **{}** button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `p` a `static` variable, declared outside of `main`:

```
static Product[] p = new Product[3];
```

But you should of course first ensure that doing something like that makes sense in the context of your program.

Comment: its not working it is giving me error like error: illegal start of expression

Comment: @SYEDSAADALI Declare `p` *outside* of `main` as `static` (exactly like above); remove the `p` that you declare within `main`. There should be no compilation errors here.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in a method are only in that method. So you need to initialize your variable outside of your methods and under the class itself. After that, you can make the variable `static` so you don't need to create an instance of the class by using:

`static Product[] p = new Product[3];`

after `public class someClass {`. Note that this makes the value of the variable the same in all instances of that class, so you can use it in any method in the class by just using `p`.